# jQuery DataTables not working in Lightning Component Spring 17

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, locker-service, spring17

I'm having issues with jQuery Datatables in a lightning component. I just tested on a Spring 17 sandbox. I'm getting this error thrown when the datatable tries to initialize. I'm using jQuery v2.2.4 and jQuery datatables v1.10.11

[image]

I have quite a few lightning components running in production environments using jQuery Datatables, and I want to make sure that everything will work nicely when the Locker Service update is mandatory in the Summer 17 release.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Realistically, you're going to want to ditch DataTables. There's no guarantee it'll be working in five months. Besides, sorting, pagination, and filtering are trivial in Lightning. I wrote two of the three in less than a work day, and if I'd thought about it, I'm sure I could have done all three at once in a day. Lightning is meant to replace jQuery, and it largely does. Personally, I'd advise against using jQuery for such trivial purposes.

Comment: @sfdcfox Well I can agree most part of it, but I believe Lightning is never meant to replace jQuery, there are lots of difference between them. As you know, Lightning is a JS Framework which enforces lots of stuffs you should do to work on it whereas jQuery is a utility library whose primary goal to ease DOM Manipulation. With that said, I see no harm in using jquery datatable in LC, you can do so much with it. Using 3rd party libraries with Locker enabled is bit noisy at the moment, I believe things will get better with each release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first report of this specific issue - Locker's design is required to be secure by default and the issue is that the name attribute is only supported on a subset of DOM elements:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name

and that set does not include HTMLTableSectionElement. Locker's secure virtual DOM is not as permissive about setting nonsensical attributes as browsers are.

Technically this is a bug in Datatable.

I believe the fix for this will be to treat this as a pseudo standard and simply add name universally to our metadata (whitelist) for HTMLElememt.

Do you already have a support case open for this?

Comment: I have not opened a support case for this. Could you point me to where I would open a case?